# Most common Spark error

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark Standalone Cluster which is doing nothing. It has such properties.

```
spark.executor.memory 5g
spark.driver.memory 5g
spark.cores.max 10
spark.deploy.defaultCores 5
```

And I have an app which creates SparkContext (which points to my cluster) and then apply some action on rdd. And it fails after first action with this extremely popular error:

```
Initial has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

Ok. As I understood I got this error after I have asked more cores/memory than cluster could provide me. It is ok but I do not ask any resources in my app (I do not specify neither --executor-memory nor --total-executor-cores) Then what it can be?

PS: Cluster seems to be fine because I can submit some jar through  ./bin/submit and it works. But with this app it does not even appear in "Running Applications" section of server's web interface.

Comment: You have a worker already doing a job.

Comment: No I dont have. When I try to execute an app cluster is free

Comment: Maybe a zombie process.

Comment: Could you post tail from worker logs?

Comment: Actually tail from Master log did help. It seems I have different version of spark.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your firewall settings.

> The host firewall on the host where I ran my PySpark shell rejected the connection attempts back from the worker nodes. 
>   After allowing all traffic between all nodes involved, the problem was resolved! 
>   The driver host was another VM in the same OpenStack project, 
>   so allowing all traffic between the VMs in the same project was OK to do security-wise.

[Spark – How to fix “WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources”](http://arnesund.com/2015/08/19/spark-how-to-fix-warn-taskschedulerimpl-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources/)

Comment: Thank you but I think it is not a case because I ran my app on the same machine where I have a master and a single worker